# How To Add Two List<> at run time ? Index out of range error My code Attached (ASP.net C#)

Tags: c#, asp.net, .net, list, indexing

I am trying to add two lists in a loop by adding first index value of one list to the  first index value of another list but both list are populating at run time after calculation issue is that how to track that list<> posses value at that index or not as shown below ,

```
Result[var]=first[var]+second[var]
```

complete code is give below,

```
List<double> Result = new List<double>();
        for (int var = 0; var < 30; var++)
        {
            if (first[var] == null)
            {
                first[var] = 0;
            }
            if (second[var] == null)
            {
                second[var] = 0;
            }
        }

       Result[var]=first[var]+second[var];
}
```

we do are not sure that both list may have value up to 10,15 .. index but i need if list one have 15 values and list two have 10 values then add two list in this way ,

```
A list[0]+B list[0]= 
A list[1]+B list[1]= 
A list[2]+B list[2]=
```

if it add

```
A list[11]+B list[11]=
```

then it add 0 from second list because it has only 10 values then how to validate b list[11] and use 0 if index 11 not exist in second list

one more thing list can have upto 30 values maximum not more then 30

Comment: Only you are a genius can understand what you mean here. Please reword your question in a way that normal humans like me can understand :) no offense.

Comment: have you not understand what ever i have written in detail ?

Comment: Honestly, No. Please reword

Comment: @Imran Thanks i think its better now !

Comment: Any reason For Down Voting ???

Answer (score 0):

You may need something like this (assuming that first and second are List):

```
List<double> Result = new List<double>();
for (int i = 0; i < 30; i++)
{
    double firstVal = 0;
    double secondVal = 0;
    if (first.Count > i)
    {
        firstVal = first[i];
    }
    if (second.Count > i)
    {
        secondVal = second[i];
    }
    Result.Add(firstVal + secondVal);
}
```

Comment: @ i think this is the solution wait i must try this .. .

Answer (score 0):

If I understood correctly, you are trying to add two list values into another list. If one of the list is ended, consider the value as zero and continue till max available limit of either of the lists.

If so,

```
// assume i1, i2 are sources and i3 is result

int max = i1.Count>i2.Count?i1.Count:i2.Count;
for (int i = 0; i < max; i++)
{
    i3[i] = (i1.Count > i ? i1[i] : 0) + (i2.Count > i ? i2[i] : 0);
}

// another varient:
for (int i = 0; i < i1.Count; i++)
{
    i3[i] = i1[i] + (i2.Count > i ? i2[i] : 0);
}
for (int i = i1.Count; i < i2.Count; i++)
{
    i3[i] = i2[i];
}
```